# Implementing Django-oscar COD

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

It has been 1 week now, and I cannot figure out the way to implement COD in django-oscar. I would be really thankful if someone can at least give me a head start to accomplish this task. I've tried to use few [Github](https://github.com/michaelkuty/django-oscar-cash-on-delivery) repositories, but either they are outdated or not clear enough to be used with the project. A head start will be good enough for me to get started from scratch.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have not yet implemented COD for Oscar, but I have been digging in the oscar source code for weeks for another non-standard payment integration. The hard part is that payment involves the checkout, basket, partner, order and payment apps. Keep the source code of the original checkout views.py file close, and refer to it often.

So what are the crucial steps:

1. All payment handling happens in the PaymentDetailsView of the checkout app, so you need a forked checkout app to start with to create a custom PaymentDetailsView subclass.
2. You need to override the **submit()** method where you create an order number, freeze the basket, save it in the session and send the pre_payment signal (just copy/paste the source code). Because payment will not be taken here, you will need to remove that part from your custom submit() implementation at this point.
3. You will then have to continue as if payment has taken place, and call **handle_order_placement()**, which will call **handle_successful_order()**
4. Afterwards, when payment has taken place upon arrival of your products you will need to implement **handle_payment()** for the relevant order number, and trigger the post_payment signal.

That's about it in a nutshell, but obviously there is some exception handling needed as well. Hope this will get you started!

Comment: Thank you for help and I will implement it.

Comment: You should not override submit() method. Just need to implement the handle_payment() method.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently implemented COD on django-oscar. Here's what you need to do.

You should understand how the checkout process of oscar works.
Let me show you in the bit. There is one 'checkout' app in the oscar which handles all the payment, placing order like stuffs. So, first of all you need to fork that app with below command.

```
./manage.py oscar_fork_app checkout apps/shop
```

Then add it in the `INSTALLED_APPS` at settings.

Now, If you look closely in the checkout app's `views.py`, there is this class [PaymentDetailsView](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/checkout/views.py#L370) which handles the placing order and payment stuff.

Now, at your preview.html page, you can add gateway option as 'cod'. When user selects this 'cod' option and submit for 'place order', you can check for submitted gateway code at the `handle_payment` method of the forked class `PaymentDetailsView`.

```
CorePaymentDetailsView = get_class('checkout.views', 'PaymentDetailsView')

class PaymentDetailsView(CorePaymentDetailsView):
    """
    currently used to redirect to preview page
    Handles the payment and cod.
    """
    def handle_payment(self, order_number, total, **kwargs):
        self.amount = float(total.excl_tax)
        gateway_code = self.request.POST.get('gateway_code', None)
        if gateway_code and gateway_code == 'cash-on-delivery':
            # Record payment source and event
            source_type, is_created = SourceType.objects.get_or_create(
                name='cash-on-delivery')
            source = source_type.sources.model(
                source_type=source_type,
                amount_allocated=total.excl_tax)
            self.add_payment_source(source)
            self.add_payment_event('CREATED', total.excl_tax)
            return
```

When you return from the `handle_payment` method, it continues executing the `submit` method of the same class and places the order.

After that you can mention at the dashboard that, this product has `cash-on-delivery` option. After delivery you can capture another payment-event as `'CASH-RECEIVED'`.

Ask if have any other query.

Comment: Let me try it and I will let you know. Thanks for help I really lost hope for it.

Comment: Yes. No worries. Take your time.